# can a return value of a function be passed in the where clause

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a python code that displays a list of station ID and air temperature for certain number of days. In the code below I have passed the dates as a list. But that is cumbersome coding since I have to write all the dates in the list. Is there any way wherein I can pass the return value of a function to the where clause. I want to know how a range of values with start and end date can be passed in the query below. Following is the code snippet:

```
import MySQLdb
import os,sys
import datetime
path="C:/Python27/"
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",user = "root", passwd = "CIMIS",db = "cimis")
c = conn.cursor()
message = """select stationId,Date,airTemperature from cimishourly where stationId in (2,7) and Date in ('2016,01,01','2016,01,04') """
c.execute(message,)
result=c.fetchall()
for row in result:
    print(row)
conn.commit()
c.close()
```

Comment: Are you using the `execute()` method to its full potential? Looks like you can pass it variables to insert into your query.

Comment: even if i use execute, the date will still be in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can substitute the return value of a function in your query. Because `message` is just a string you can concatenate it like you would any other string.

`message = """select stationId,Date,airTemperature from cimishourly where stationId in (2,7) and Date in (""" + functionToGetDates() + """)"""`

The parentheses can be formatted in the function or in the original string like I chose to do.

Comment: The function i am trying is as follows :                                                                                   import datetime
 
def date_range(start, end):
    r = (end+datetime.timedelta(days=1)-start).days
    return [start+datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(r)]
 
start = datetime.date(2016,01,01)
end = datetime.date(2016,01,04)
dateList = date_range(start, end)
print '\n'.join([str(date) for date in dateList]) . I am passing the function yet getting an error

Comment: cannot concatenate str and datetime.timedelta objects

Comment: when doing that concatenation, do `'start of string' + str(dateTimeObject) + 'end of string'`